# mouse event on picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I want to see my pixel coordinates on moviing my mouse on the image in picture box

I have added this event Form.designer.cs

```
this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseDown);
```

and this method in Form.cs

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{          
    locationtxt.Text = e.X.ToString() + "," + e.Y.ToString();
}
```

but I cann't see anything in textbox on moving my mouse on form runtime.

What should i add further.
regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach to the picturebox's event, not this, and to the MouseMove event, not MouseDown.